# Programmatically tag an untagged pdf with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, tagged-pdf

I want to parse a PDF file with iTextSharp. With tagged PDFs I used TaggedPdfReaderTool and the .ConvertToXml() method which returned me an acceptable XML for further parsing. Now I have to parse untagged PDFs which I need to parse! In Adobe Acrobat you can add tags to a PDF using their accessibility tool. After that I'm able to parse it with iTextSharp. Now I'm looking for a free solution to add tags to my PDF programmatically (with iTextSharp). In the book "iText in Action" I've read that you can create a tagged PDF (from an XML file) but i need to convert an existing one!

My code for parsing tagged PDFs:

```
        var path = @"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx.pdf";
        var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx_tagged.xml", FileMode.Create);

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
        TaggedPdfReaderTool tool = new TaggedPdfReaderTool();
        tool.ConvertToXml(reader, fs);
        fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an easy problem. Since you are essentially asking for a solution to do structure recognition.

Think about it. You want to know where paragraphs begin and end, you'd need a solution for figuring out tables and lists. Not to mention nested tables and lists and combinations thereof.

This is the topic of research. One popular approach is to use neural networks (treating the pdf as an image and tackling it as an image recognition task), or alternatively tackle it in a rule-based fashion.

Comment: But is Adobe Acrobat using machine learning to tag PDFs? So i guess it's not possible with iTextSharp? Is there an easy to use framework which uses neural networks to get the job done. I'm not willing to invest a lot of energy (which obviously would be needed) to do this since it's a small job. Only other approach I could come up with is to buy Acrobat, download SDK and get this automated tagging feature invoked programmatically. I cannot share the PDF but besides some text I want to parse a table with values. In Acrobat's tagged version it's a <table> object with some <th>, <tr> and <td>s.

Comment: You could always abduct a team of developers and research engineers, put them to work, and hope they finish the job before they starve. That would probably be the lowest-cost solution to your problem, although they abduction part of the scheme might take some  energy. Moreover, being a developer myself, I would advice against such a solution. It wouldn't be ethical and there's always be the risk that I would be one of the abductees :D